# Visual Studio C++ and Python, working with Input file, FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am using Visual Studio working with C++, a Python File, and an .txt input file. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Project3Week7\Release\PythonCode.py", line 8, in CountAll
    text =open ("ProjectThreeInput.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ProjectThreeInput.txt'
```

My input file is named ProjectThreeInput.txt. It is located in the release folder in my C++ project. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I am getting this error?

Here is my Python code:

```
import re
import string
import os.path
from os import path

#open read me file
def CountAll():
    text =open ("ProjectThreeInput.txt","r")

    # empty dictionary, remove white space, convert to lowercase, check if in dict, print functions, close file
    dictionary = dict()
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        word = line.lower()
        
        if word in dictionary:
            dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1
        else:
            dictionary[word] = 1

     #print dicitonary
    for key in list (dictionary.keys()):
        print(key.capitalize(), ":", dictionary[key])

     #close file
    text.close()


#word count, convert to lower case, open file, convert to lower case, check for word return count, close
def CountInstances(serchTerm):
    searchTerm = searchTerm.lower
    text = open("ProjectThreeInput.txt","r")
    wordCount = 0
    
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        word = line.lower()
        if word == searchTerm:
            wordCount +=1
    return wordCount
    text.close()

# frequency.dat, open file, create empty dict, store words, remove spaces, convert to lower case, check if in dict, write key to freq.dat, close
def CollectData():
    text = open("ProjectThreeInput.txt","r")
    frequency = open("frequency.dat", "w")
    dictionary = dict()

    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        word = line.lower()
        if word in dictionary:
            dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1
        else:
            dictionary[word] = 1

    for key in list (dictionary.keys()):
        frequency.write(str(key.capitaize()) + " " + str(dictionary[key]) + "\n")

    text.close()
    frequency.close()
```

Comment: from which directory you are running the code?
Does that directory has the file `ProjectThreeInput.txt`?

Comment: Yes, that input file is in the same directory (release folder) as my other files including the pythoncode file

Comment: are you running the python file from inside the release folder?
You can also try giving the absolute path of `ProjectThreeInput.txt`.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are very different tools. Which one are you using here?

Comment: visual studio. Sorry, I didn't realize I tagged the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Visual Studio starts a C++ program in the project directory, where the .vcxproj* files live, and not where the executables are built. You can configure that directory in the project properties, under Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory. In your case, set it to **$(OutputPath)**. Be sure to select "All Configurations" (and all platforms, if there are multiple) at the top of the dialog. This setting is stored in the .vcxproj.user file.

Or alternatively, you could generate the executable in the directory where keep input files, by changing Configuration Properties > General > Output Directory. But then you risk mixing up artifacts from Debug and Release configurations. Instead you could redefine only Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Output File and include $(ConfigurationName) in that file name.

Comment: I checked the working directory. It was already set for $(OutputPath). I did change it to "All Configurations" but I still get the same error message.

Comment: I thought you had a C++ project with C++ code equivalent to the pyton code, but now it seems you have a utility or makefile project invoking python? Then I don't quite remember where  $(OutputPath) leads (I think the directory of the optional target) to but you can just see in the python code what `os.getcwd()` is.